# wp.editor.initialize does not show the same default toolbar

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

In a custom post type of my plugin, for the edit post page, there is a WP Editor inside a metabox.
In this metabox there is a button to add WP Editors via jQuery and Ajax.
I managed to do it but `wp.editor.initialize( response.html.editor_id, { tinymce : true } );` does not show the same default toolbar than `wp_editor();` in php used to init the first WP Editor.

**First WP Editor loaded by PHP**

[image]

**Second WP Editor loaded by jQuery**

[image]

How can I get the same default toolbar for each tinymce ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for full fledged editor.(**You have to make some changes by your own**)

```
wp.editor.initialize ( 'EditorTextArea' , {

tinymce: {
    wpautop: to true ,
    theme: 'modern' ,
    skin: 'lightgray' ,
    language: 'en' ,
    formats: {
        alignleft: [
            {selector: 'p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, td, th, div, ul, ol, li' , styles: {textAlign: 'left' }},
            {selector: 'img, table, dl.wp-caption' , classes: 'alignleft' }
        ],
        aligncenter: [
            {selector: 'p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, td, th, div, ul, ol, li' , styles: {textAlign: 'center' }},
            {selector: 'img, table, dl.wp-caption' , classes: 'aligncenter' }
        ],
        alignright: [
            {selector: 'p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, td, th, div, ul, ol, li' , styles: {textAlign: 'right' }},
            {selector: 'img, table, dl.wp-caption' , classes: 'alignright' }
        ],
        strikethrough: {inline: 'del' }
    },
    relative_urls: false ,
    remove_script_host: false ,
    convert_urls: false ,
    browser_spellcheck: to true ,
    fix_list_elements: to true ,
    entities: '38, amp, 60, lt, 62, gt ' ,
    entity_encoding: 'raw' ,
    keep_styles: false ,
    paste_webkit_styles: 'font-weight font-style color' ,
    preview_styles: 'font-family font-size font-weight font-style text-decoration text-transform' ,
    tabfocus_elements: ': prev ,: next' ,
    plugins: 'charmap, hr, media, paste, tabfocus, textcolor, fullscreen, wordpress, wpeditimage, wpgallery, wplink, wpdialogs, wpview' ,
    resize: 'vertical' ,
    menubar: false ,
    indent: false ,
    toolbar1: 'bold, italic, strikethrough, bullist, numlist, blockquote, hr, alignleft, aligncenter, alignright, link, unlink, wp_more, spellchecker, fullscreen, wp_adv' ,
    toolbar2: 'formatselect, underline, alignjustify, forecolor, pastetext, removeformat, charmap, outdent, indent, undo, redo, wp_help' ,
    toolbar3: '' ,
    toolbar4: '' ,
    body_class: 'id post-type-post-status-publish post-format-standard' ,
    wpeditimage_disable_captions: false ,
    wpeditimage_html5_captions: true

},
Quicktags: true,
mediaButtons: true
```

})

You can also check look at here: 
https://gist.github.com/rheinardkorf/aec4d46d3833d2f7a6a27c4481ba0b44

https://wp-kama.ru/question/wp-editor-initialize

Let me know if you are facing any issue in this.

Comment: Thank you BUT your solution is hard coded. I need to get dynamically settings. As you can see, there are different buttons from others plugins like wpDataTables for example.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add this code for same layout for wp

```
wp.editor.initialize(editor_id,{
    tinymce: {
      wpautop: true,
      plugins : 'charmap colorpicker hr lists paste tabfocus textcolor fullscreen wordpress wpautoresize wpeditimage wpemoji wpgallery wplink wptextpattern',
      toolbar1: 'formatselect,bold,italic,bullist,numlist,blockquote,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,link,wp_more,spellchecker,fullscreen,wp_adv,listbuttons',
      toolbar2: 'styleselect,strikethrough,hr,forecolor,pastetext,removeformat,charmap,outdent,indent,undo,redo,wp_help',
      textarea_rows : 20
    },
    quicktags: {buttons: 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,more,close'},
    mediaButtons: false,
});
```